# How could this worker thread be blocked yet show running?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have a multithreaded task queue running four worker threads. The worker routine is as follows:

```
void worker() {
    task_t task;

    while (true) {
        try {
            pthread_setname_np("waiting");

            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{mutex_m};

            condition_m.wait(lock, [=](){ return done_m || !deque_m.empty(); });

            if (done_m)
                return;

            // try to pop a task off the deque. Returns true iff the deque's
            // front task was moved out of the deque into task.
            if (try_pop_unsafe(task)) {
                lock.unlock();

                pthread_setname_np("RUNNING");

                task();
            }
        } catch (...) {
            // Drop it on the floor. Not ideal, but really there's nowhere
            // for them to go right now.
        }
    }
}
```

You will notice there are two locations where the name of the thread is set: at the top of the `while` loop, and right before a task is to be executed. When the thread is blocked and waiting for a task, it should show `waiting` in its name. While the worker is working, it should show `RUNNING`.

In the course of debugging I have discovered that there are worker threads blocked by `condition_m.wait(...)`, yet showing `RUNNING`. How can this be? Is it an IDE snafu, or is there a path in the worker function that could account for it?

Comment: What is the `lock_t`?

Comment: @Alex `lock_t` is a `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>`, and have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried to check the `pthread_setname_np()` return value?

Comment: @Alex I have not - thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

If the task itself is blocking it could remain running.

Or, if the task throws an exception, the catch statement merely exits the function leaving the thread to remain in a "RUNNING" state until the thread is joined. Perhaps introducing a "DEAD" or "EXCEPTION" state may be good here?

What OS are you running on and with what IDE?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `lock_t` is a `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>`, and will unlock on destruction. At the end of the try block, then, regardless of an exception or normal control flow, the lock should be free. Even so, that doesn't explain how the while loop can iterate again, and the `pthread_name_sp` call seemingly bypassed. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: I'm running on a Mac with Xcode 6. An exception won't terminate the while loop - it will iterate until `done_m` is `true`.

Comment: Also, if the task is blocking that's fine, and should show `RUNNING` - it's the case when it's blocked at the top of the while loop by the condition variable that I am puzzled about. Sorry, I should have made that more clear. I have updated the question to reflect your observation. Thanks.